# Post json reponse returns 500 error instead of 200 using python. Request call returns 500 while same call on postman returns data

Tags: json, post, response

```
    proxies = {
    'http': f'{self.doc.http_proxy_url}:{self.doc.http_proxy_port}',
     https': f'{self.doc.http_proxy_url}:{self.doc.http_proxy_port}'
          }
   requestHeaders1 = {
   'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token,
   'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=UTF-8',
    'tenant': '07da27b9-e911-4d2e-826c-2a4feeb4f35a'
        }
    with open('Ingest_APMAlarms.json') as json_file:
            json_data = json.load(json_file)
    url1 = apmEnvAttr.alerts_ingestion_url
    r1 = requests.post(url1,
                   verify=False,
                   proxies=proxies,
                   headers=requestHeaders1,
                   json=json.dumps(json_data)),
```

When I do same request using postman it does return valid json response but when I am trying through code it returns 500 response. Content of Ingest_APMAlarms.json file looks like below.

```
"taskList": [
    {
      "taskId": "ABC_25_b5d2da6f-17ff-4476-9652-5e64e3c68381|9|100|9_1|2656",
      "type": "upsertAlarm",
      "body": {
        "name": "NetDDE Exporter Failed to Start.",
        "source": "System1",
        "sourceKey": "DS-S1C-25_b5d2da6f-17ff-4476-9652-5e64e3c68381_9_100_9_1_test25Final",
        "templated": "false",
        "templateName": "System1_Events",
        "severity": 0,
        "eventStart": "2018-07-05T21:03:52.638",
        "associatedMonitoredEntitySourceKey": "DS-S1C-25_b5d2da6f-17ff-4476-9652-5e64e3c68381",
        "incident": {},
        "tagsOfInterest": {
          "uuid": "DS-S1C-25_b5d2da6f-17ff-4476-9652-5e64e3c68381_System1",
          "isContributing": "true",
          "displayGrouped": "true",
          "displayGroupName": "System1",
          "uom": "uom"
        },
        "enterpriseName": "DS-S1C-25",
        "enterpriseId": "DS-S1C-25_b5d2da6f-17ff-4476-9652-5e64e3c68381",
        "daqId": "9_1",
        "assetNamePath": "DS-S1C-25->System1",
        "assetPath": "DS-S1C-25->100",
        "machineTrainName": null,
        "machineTrainId": null,
        "machineName": null,
        "machineId": "100",
        "trainMachine": "",
        "pointName": null,
        "pointId": null,
        "nodeName": "System1",
        "eventCategory": "system",
        "description": "NetDDE Exporter Failed to Start.",
        "sourceHierarchy": "Device",
        "entered": "2018-06-28T21:59:46.734",
        "exited": null,
        "sourceType": "Not Transient",
        "customerId": "08b00700-1326-4e60-bdf8-3016f0f4d588",
        "groupId": "EIDEVA_2",
        "activity": "Active"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: you missed '(quote) , `https': f'{self.doc.http_proxy_url}:{self.doc.http_proxy_port}'` should be `'https': f'{self.doc.http_proxy_url}:{self.doc.http_proxy_port}'`, or check anywhere else did you missed it or not, quote matters in programming so be careful and check what error you got while executing above code, paste that too in question which will help SO members to answer your question.

Comment: proxies values are getting correctly into code.Response return from the call is 500 while same call through postman returns 200.

Comment: can you add quote and try, because I could see there is '(quote) mismatch in the code you posted above.paste this `proxies = {
    'http': f'{self.doc.http_proxy_url}:{self.doc.http_proxy_port}',
     'https': f'{self.doc.http_proxy_url}:{self.doc.http_proxy_port}'
          }`

Comment: Sorry quote mistmatch was while pasting the code. On my code I have correct quote

Comment: I am not sure if its ok to pass json file in the code the way I am passing. Can you please check on that. I have pasted content of my json file

Comment: should the json file structure needs to be converted into string

Comment: try putting json as in single line(without indentation) in file.

Comment: I tried that too and it does not work, I verified that data is getting whole json but still response is 500.